# Ubuntu runtime error

Tags: dual-boot

I installed ubuntu on windows 10, went through all stages fine include Hd space 28gb, after reboot it gave me option windows 10 or Ubuntu, selected Ubuntu, 
then 1st this error displayed:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:
1. Insert your windows installation disk and restart pc, 
2. choose your language setting and click next, 
3. click repair your computer. 
File:\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr   status: 0xc00007b.
```

I tried to reboot and went to Windows 10, tried Windows updates, installed winrar, then copied Ubuntu folder to desktop, tried to open, discovered some of the files changed to winrar/zip folders, then rebooted again, went to Ubuntu and new error displayed status: `0xc000000f`.

Comment: Please explain your problem clearly

Comment: Avoid Wubi or try a [community supported version](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases) with UEFI support.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are installing Ubuntu using Wubi. Wubi is discontinued. Please use the proper Live installer to install Ubuntu.

Comment: thank you, is proper live installer from here? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: @CostaMtagwaba Yes.